# обновление базы данных после изменений у конечного пользователя

Tags: c#, база-данных, entity-framework, codefirst

Такой вот вопрос, может есть тут разработчики, которые подскажут, как можно выйти с такой ситуации.

По модели Code First Entity Framework пишем код, по нему создаем базу все как положена и тп. Чтобы сделать какое-то обновление в базе данных - делаем миграцию и updatе'им базу. Но это мы можем сделать на стороне как разработчика. Как сделать обновление базы на стороне конечного пользователя, не устанавливая при этом никаких инструментов разработчиков? К примеру, создали клиенту базу, через месяц он захотел поменять структуру, у себя мы изменили, как изменить у него?
Спасибо заранее за ответ!

Comment: можно сделать `Update-Database -Script`. Обновления запишутся в sql скрипт. Скрипт можно будет выполнить у клиента. [документация](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/migrations/index?redirectedfrom=MSDN#getting-a-sql-script)

Comment: @Ruslan_K если скрипт выполнить у клиента, оно обновит данные или удалит и заново построит БД (в таком случае потеряются все данные)?